# cookie is not savaed by browser for localhost while redirect

Tags: http, cookies

I cannot mange to set cookie from server side for localhost in a way any browser accept them with 302 response. When browser receive response I can see next headers (some of them):

```
Request URL: https://non-localhost-server-url
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
location: http://127.0.0.1:8081/
Server: nginx
set-cookie: token=XXXXXXXXX; Version=1; Domain=127.0.0.1; Path=/
Request Headers
view source
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,uk;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8081/login
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
```

but browser doesn't save cookie (I'm checking it in content settings in Chrome). I've tried to set cookies' domain to localhost and not set domain at all, but it didn't help.
Maybe some additional headers should be present? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is **not** "localhost"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Request URL: https://non-localhost-server-url
> ```

An HTTP response can only set cookies for the domain the request was made to.

You can't redirect to a different domain and set cookies that are intended for there.

It would be a major security problem if a website could set cookies for an arbitary different website.

Comment: Can I bypass this limitation somehow in different browsers?

Comment: No. It would be a major security problem if you could.